# Perl: Assign a value to a variable only when it is to be used

Tags: windows, perl, variables

This is in perl Windows.

Code Snippet:

```
    my $TestVarDirName;
    my $testScript = "U:/perl.exe U:/devAuto.pl -p SHELL=/usr/bin/bash $TestVarDirName -t lnx64"; 
    &runAndMonitor(\@ForRun, "$MSROO/logs/Test.log");

    $testScript = "U:/perl.exe U:/devAuto.pl -p SHELL=/usr/hash -m win -serial 32 $TestVarDirName -t wint";    ### Added 
    &runAndMonitor(\@ForRun2, "$MSROO/logs/Test2.log"); ### Added

     sub runAndMonitor {
        my @ForRunPerProduct =  @{$_[0]};
        my $logFile = $_[1];
            foreach my $TestVar (@ForRunPerProduct) {
                print "$testScript is the testScript command\n";  ### Line 9
                $TestVarDirName = $TestVar;
                $TestVarDirName = dirname ($TestVarDirName);
                my $filehandle;       
               if ( !($pid = open( $filehandle, "-|" , " $bashexe -c \"cd $smokesBasePath \; $testScript \" >> $logFile ""))) {                
                    die( "Failed to start process: $!" );
                }
           }
     }
```

I want that in piped open command, `$testScript` variable substitutes the value of `$TestVarDirName` only when `$testScript` is called (dynamically), and not in the start of the script.

Currently, at "line 9" (as mentioned in code snippet), I am getting `U:/perl.exe U:/devAuto.pl -p SHELL=/usr/bin/bash  -t lnx64 is the testScript command`. Of course because initially at the start of script, `$TestVarDirName` has no value in it, and command would work according to its initial value. How can I avoid it, and let the latest value of `$TestVarDirName` be used?

Comment: Can you not assemble the whole `my $testScript = ...` right before it's used?  (Is it shared among different code segments? If not then you _want_ to declare it where it's used.)

Comment: @zdim, Yes, it is used among different code segments, and that too in a common section (inside a common function). So, can't declare where it is used.

Answer (score 2):

Use an anonymous sub to build the string:

```
my $testScriptBuilder = sub { "U:/perl.exe U:/devAuto.pl -p SHELL=/usr/bin/bash $_[0] -t lnx64" }; 
...
foreach my $TestVar (@ForRunPerProduct) {
    local $TestVarDirName = dirname($TestVar);
    my $testScript = $testScriptBuilder->($TestVarDirName);
    ....
}
```

If you think that having `$_[0]` instead of `$TestVarDirName` in the string makes things less clear, then you could use this sub instead:

```
my $testScriptBuilder = sub { 
    my $TestVarDirName = $_[0];
    return "U:/perl.exe U:/devAuto.pl -p SHELL=/usr/bin/bash $TestVarDirName -t lnx64" 
};
```

The interpolation of `$_[0]` (or `$TestVarDirName`) in `"U:/perl.exe U:/devAuto.pl -p SHELL=/usr/bin/bash $_[0] -t lnx64"` is only done when the subroutine `testScriptBuilder` is evaluated, which is when you actually call it with `testScriptBuilder->($TestVarDirName)`. Thus, `$TestVarDirName` will have the expected value (`dirname($TestVar)`).

---

Alternatively, you could use the [`Template`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) module:

```
my $testScriptTemplate = "U:/perl.exe U:/devAuto.pl -p SHELL=/usr/bin/bash [% TestVarDirName %] -t lnx64";
...
foreach my $TestVar (@ForRunPerProduct) {
  my $TestVarDirName = dirname($TestVar);
  Template->new->process(\$testScriptTemplate, { TestVarDirName => $TestVarDirName }, \my $testScript);
  ...
}
```

The downside is that you have to modify the initial string in a more intrusive manner (replacing `$TestVarDirName` by `[% TestVarDirName %]`). However, this is also an upside, as it allows you to specify what should be interpolated early and what shouldn't: all of the variables in the template string will be interpolated right away, while the things inside `[% %]` will be interpolated later.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the edit. Still, `String::Interpolate` is a bit weird, and the code with your edit doesn't work, and my previous code worked. While the documentation says "cannot be lexical", it actually must be lexical in order to work (and `->lexicals(1)` is enabled by default when calling `interpolate`). I don't think that what I'm doing is the primary intended use-case of `String::Interpolate`, so I'll remove this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked a little, but I have to use it multiple times. I edited a code, and added two new lines. Can you please guide now?

Comment: I see. I'm sorry to say, but you need to rethink the logic of your program. For instance, you should surely pass `$testScript` as a 3rd argument to `runAndMonitor `.

Answer (score 0):

[Dada's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443263/1990570) is the sane way of doing this, but if you'd like a less sane way...

```perl
use String::Interpolate::Delayed;

my $TestVarDirName;
my $testScript = delayed "U:/perl.exe U:/devAuto.pl -p SHELL=/usr/bin/bash $TestVarDirName -t lnx64"; 
&runAndMonitor(\@ForRun, "$MSROO/logs/Test.log");

sub runAndMonitor {
    my @ForRunPerProduct =  @{$_[0]};
    my $logFile = $_[1];
        foreach my $TestVar (@ForRunPerProduct) {
            print "$testScript is the testScript command\n";  ### Line 9
            $TestVarDirName = $TestVar;
            $TestVarDirName = dirname ($TestVarDirName);
            my $filehandle;       
           if ( !($pid = open( $filehandle, "-|" , " $bashexe -c \"cd $smokesBasePath \; $testScript \" >> $logFile ""))) {                
                die( "Failed to start process: $!" );
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a much simpler way to go here. Set up a template for the string you want, then fill in the placeholders when you are ready to use it. No fancy subroutine tricks or modules:

```
 my $testScript_template = "U:/perl.exe ... %s -t lnx64"; 

 sub runAndMonitor {
    ...
    foreach my $TestVar (@ForRunPerProduct) {
        ...
        $TestVarDirName = dirname ($TestVarDirName);
        $testScript = sprintf $testScript_template, $TestVarDirName;
        ...
   }
 }
```

But I might move that template into the smallest scope it needs:

```
 sub runAndMonitor {
    ...
    foreach my $TestVar (@ForRunPerProduct) {
        state $testScript_template = "U:/perl.exe ... %s -t lnx64"; 
        ...
        $TestVarDirName = dirname ($TestVarDirName);
        $testScript = sprintf $testScript_template, $TestVarDirName;
        ...
   }
 }
```